# Bash script to restart process on crash or on file change

Tags: bash, process, scripting, build-automation

I'm coding a server process, and I want to make a Bash script that will restart the process in either of two conditions:

1. The current process exits (in this case, restart after some delay)
2. The executable is modified (in this case, restart immediately)

The script itself should not exit in either condition.

I can do either of these things (with a simple loop, or with fswatch), but my attempts to do both have not worked.  Is there a way to do both in a Bash script?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with fswatch, but assuming you have set opts and path such that it will write data only when the file you care about changes and you're not worried about buffering, you can try:

```
fswatch $opts $path | while read k; do kill $pid; done &
while sleep 1; do  # delay 1 second between restarts
  cmd &
  pid=$!
  wait $pid
done
```

This does not restart immediately when the executable changes.  To get that, you could do (but I don't think it's worthwhile):

```
fswatch $opts $path | while read k; do kill $pid; done &
while : ; do  
  cmd &
  pid=$!
  wait $pid
  test $? -gt 128 || sleep 1
done
```

Comment: I am not 100% sure, that in 2nd case, the `$?` based test is reliable. In both case it's the exit status from same process. so, it may not be able to differentiate between 2 failure cases... Can we set a variable in fswatch based loop (we would need process redirection for that or `shopt -s lastpipe`) & use it in `while true` loop?